# How to create ".dll" file from xUnit project, using msys2 and mono?

Tags: asp.net-core, mono, xunit, xunit.net, msys2

I have `xUnit` project in `.Net Core` framework and what I need is to create the `.dll` from this project, using the console. The project has many classes for test cases.

I am using `mono` and `msys2` and I need to compile the project using these technologies.
I was able to create some `.dll` file using the command

```
mcs /path/to/xUnit/project/*.cs /target:library /out:MyDll.dll /recurse:*.cs
```

But it seems it's not working well, since when I try to use this `dll` file, I got the error:

```
xUnit.net Console Runner v2.4.1 (64-bit Desktop .NET 4.5.2, runtime: 4.0.30319.42000)
System.InvalidOperationException: Unknown test framework: could not find xunit.dll (v1) or xunit.execution.*.dll (v2) in /path/to/xUnit/project
```

I further tried to build it like:

```
mcs /path/to/xUnit/project/*.cs /target:library /out:MyDll.dll /recurse:*.cs -r:/path/to/xUnit/project/bin/Debug/xunit.core.dll
```

But still not success. **So my question will be**: how can I create a `.dll` file from `xUnit` project, using `mono` and `msys2`?